# Log4j Duplicate logging with additivity set to false

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to log to a file, if the logging is called from a specific package, and otherwise log to console. So I set the additivity to false for the two loggers which should be logging to file, so nothing would be logged on the console for these two packages. My log4j.xml is as follows:

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="TRACE"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">

    <!-- Set your own log file location -->
    <param name="File" value="c:/temp/security-toolkit.log" />

    <!-- Specify the number of backup -->
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>

    <!-- Specify the file size -->
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p[%X{event} %X{user_name}:%X{user_sid}@%X{user_last_host_address} -> /%X{application_name}/%X{module_name}] %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>



<root>      
    <priority value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
</root>

<logger name="com.foo.security" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.foo.esapi" additivity="false">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="file"/>
</logger>
```

However, logs from com.foo.security are still being logged to the console. Does anyone know what the issue could be here?

Comment: But they are also logged to the file? Can you add the line where you create the loggers?